# In Javascript, how would I take the output of browserUserAgent for Edge and converti it into Edge's browser version?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am working on a Browser Check for the school that I work at. I have a .js file where I am pulling information to a html page to display the name of the browser and the its version. Unfortunately with Windows Edge the token that is displayed is 13.1 or 12.1 depending on which version of Edge you are using.

These are the edgeHTML versions not the actual displayed version for Edge. 
I have been trying to find a way to display the actual Edge versions 20 and 25 but not getting anywhere.

I have tried using IF ELSE statements but when I do it just renders the number listed in the second line of the IF part of the statement no matter if I am using Edge 20 or 25.  Please help.

```
case browserUserAgent.indexOf('edge') >= -1: // browser is Edge, check the gorilla first
    browserAgent = 'Edge';
    browserVersion = browserUserAgent.split('edge/');
    browserVersion = browserVersion[1].split(0, 3);
    browserVersion = browserVersion[0];
    if (browserVersion = '12.1') {
        browserVersion = '20';
    } else if (browserVersion = '13.1') {
        browserVersion = '25';
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Just curious, what's "the gorilla"? ;)

Comment: @damd Mozilla Gorilla? :p

Comment: @ManoDestra: One can only guess, but I'm still holding out for a gorilla

Answer (score 0):

Since (public) EdgeHTML versions maps 1-to-1 against Edge browser versions, you can do this:

```
// map (major versions of) EdgeHTML to Edge
var EDGEHTML_TO_EDGE = {
    12: 20,
    13: 25
};

// regexp which matches edge user strings
var EDGE_REGEXP = /Edge\/(\d+)/;

// check if the regexp matches the user agent
var edgeMatch = browserUserAgent.match(EDGE_REGEXP);
if (edgeRegexp) {
    var edgeHtmlVersion = edgeMatch[1]; // the major EdgeHTML version number
    var edgeVersion = EDGEHTML_TO_EDGE[edgeHtmlVersion];
    document.write('You are running Edge ' + edgeVersion);
}
```

EDIT: A much simpler and straight forward method:

```
if (/Edge\/12\.1/.test(browserUserAgent)) {
    document.write('You are running Edge 20');
} else if (/Edge\/13\.1/.test(browserUserAgent)) {
    document.write('You are running Edge 25');
}
```

I have not been able to test it myself as I don't have Edge, but it should give you the idea. I'm basically getting the *major* version number reported by the User Agent and then mapping that to the known Edge browser versions.

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to test for other browsers too, you can try the [browser](https://github.com/ded/bowser) `npm` package.